# User-Defined Function for lme model fits: error

Tags: r, nlme

I am beginning to write a function that builds linear mixed models with `nlme`. I am encountering an error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not found`, which I believe is due to R not knowing where to find the data frame variables (e.g., `value`). If this is, in fact, why the error is occurring, how do I tell the function that `value` and `timepoint` belong to the variables in `Dat` in the (reproducible) code  below?

```
require(nlme)
Dat <- data.frame(
    id = sample(10:19),
    Time = sample(c("one", "two"), 10, replace = T),
    Value = sample(1:10)
)
nlme_rct_lmm <- function (data, value, timepoint,
                      ID) {

    #base_level intercept only model
    bl_int_only <- gls(value ~ 1, 
                       data = data, 
                       method = "ML", 
                       na.action="na.omit")        
    #vary intercept across participants
    randomIntercept <- lme(value ~ 1, 
                           data = data, 
                           random = ~1|ID, 
                           method = "ML", 
                           na.action = "na.omit")       
    #add timepoint as a fixed effect
    timeFE <- lme(value ~ timepoint, 
                  data = data, 
                  random = ~1|ID, 
                  method = "ML", 
                  na.action = "na.omit")
}
nlme_rct_lmm(Dat, Value, Time, id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't (as you and I both expected) a problem with evaluation within different frames; rather, it's an issue of consistency between the names of the variables between the formula and the data.  R is case-sensitive, so it matters whether you use `value` or `Value`, `id` or `ID`, etc..  Furthermore, formula interpretation uses non-standard evaluation (NSE), so if you have a variable `value` equal to the symbol `Value`, `value ~ 1` does *not* magically get transmuted to `Value ~ 1`. What I've outlined below works by passing the *names* of the response, time, and ID variables to the function, because it's the easiest approach.  It's a little bit more elegant to the end-user if you use non-standard evaluation, but that's a bit harder to program (and therefore understand, debug, etc.).

Below the easy/boneheaded approach, I also discuss how to implement the NSE approach (scroll all the way down ...)

Note that your example doesn't return anything; with R, that means that all the results will be discarded when it finishes the function. You might want to return the results as a list (or perhaps your real function will do something other stuff with the fitted models, such as a series of model tests, and return those answers as the results ...)

```
require(nlme)

Dat <- data.frame(
    ID = sample(10:19),
    Time = sample(c("one", "two"), 10, replace = T),
    Value = sample(1:10)
)

nlme_rct_lmm <- function (data, value, timepoint,
                      ID) {

    nullmodel <- reformulate("1",response=value)
    fullmodel <- reformulate(c("1",timepoint),response=value)
    remodel <- reformulate(paste("1",ID,sep="|"))

    #base_level intercept only model
    bl_int_only <- gls(nullmodel,
                       data = data, 
                       method = "ML", 
                       na.action="na.omit")

    #vary intercept across participants
    randomIntercept <- lme(nullmodel,
                           data = data, 
                           random = remodel,
                           method = "ML", 
                           na.action = "na.omit")

    #add timepoint as a fixed effect
    timeFE <- lme(fullmodel,
                  data = data, 
                  random = remodel,
                  method = "ML", 
                  na.action = "na.omit")
}

nlme_rct_lmm(Dat, "Value", "Time", "ID")
```

If you want something a bit more elegant (but internally obscure) you can substitute the following lines for defining the models. The inner `substitute()` calls retrieves the *symbols* that were passed to the function as arguments; the outer `substitute()` calls insert those symbols into the formula.

```
nullmodel <- formula(substitute(v~1,list(v=substitute(value))))
fullmodel <- formula(substitute(v~t,list(v=substitute(value),
                                 t=substitute(timepoint))))
remodel <- formula(substitute(~1|i,list(i=substitute(ID))))
```

Now this would work, without specifying the variables as strings, as you expected: `nlme_rct_lmm(Dat, Value, Time, ID)`

Comment: That occurred to me but I thought that this might be just the beginning of the OP's example (e.g. that they might do some other stuff with the results before returning a summary value); worth mentioning in the answer anyway ...

Comment: Excellent! Yes, the actual function is returning a series of model tests. I find the NSE approach to be, as mentioned, more end-user friendly.